# Set active tab for angular `mat-tab-nav-bar`

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, mat-tab

I have the following `not working` code (found in some incomplete example):

```html
<nav mat-tab-nav-bar>
    <a mat-tab-link *ngFor="let device of devices$ | async" [routerLink]="device.getIp()"
        [routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive"
        [active]="rla.isActive">
    </a>
</nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

I am not sure how is this suppose to work:

- Should I have `routerLinkActive` defined in my `ts`?
- What does `[routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive"` mean?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Remove the `[` before routerLinkActive, I am not sure whether it is a typo or not, but it is not necessary. I tried to give it a more logical order.

```
<nav mat-tab-nav-bar>
  <a *ngFor="let device of devices$ | async" 
     [routerLink]="device.getIp()"
     routerLinkActive
     #rla="routerLinkActive"
     mat-tab-link
     [active]="rla.isActive">
  </a>
</nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

That code should be correct. There are some things going on there. So each `<a>` tag will have the `mat-tab-link` directive that connects it to `mat-tab-nav-bar`, and also styles the button, but it needs an input (boolean) that will set it as active or inactive, hence the `[active]` input.
Documentation for it here: 
https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/examples

Now you need to know how to mark it as active, so `[routerLink]` input will set the route that link is pointing at, and the `routerLinkActive` is a directive that will tell whether that route is active or not. 
Check the API here:
https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive

So what you are doing in your code is, you are assigning that `routerLinkActive` directive instance to a variable named `rla` with this `#rla="routerLinkActive"`, then you can access to the `isActive` property, so you set the input `[active]` of `mat-tab-link` to the property in the `rla` directive instance with `[active]="rla.isActive"`. No need to handle any of that in the ts file.

Comment: I make a stackblitz with your idea, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-o8jf3u?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftab-group-basic-example.html (You're so quicky in response.. :)

Comment: Cool, I was actually looking for a `stackblitz` example before asking here. Thanks.

Comment: On the stackblitz, I change the property index to 1, but tab /two is not preselected, is this the right way to do it? tnx